# error using LoadBitmap using MAKEINTRESOURCE

Tags: visual-c++

Im using Visual Studio 2012 using Visual C++, I have been trying to load a bitmap from my resources
 Like this:

```
HRESULT DemoApp::CreateDIBFromResource(HWND hWnd, HINSTANCE Instance, LPCWSTR ImageID)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    HBITMAP bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(0), MAKEINTRESOURCE(ImageID));

    return hr;
}
```

and calling the function like this

```
if(SUCCEEDED(CreateDIBFromResource(hWnd, NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BACKGROUND))))
{
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
}
```

It wasn't loading anything so I put a breakpoint at

```
return hr;
```

when I hover the cursor over `ImageID` it says

```
ImageID = 0x00000065 Error reading characters of string.
```

I cant figure out the problem. I have Unicode enabled and I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: It is just the debugger being confused about the PDB saying that it is a string but your code saying it is not.  It is not a string, it is a number.  You can't figure out the problem at least partly because you seem to have no error handling whatsoever.  *Never* skip that when you use the raw winapi.  Put the fake "@err" variable in a debugger watch expression to see the Windows error code.

Answer (score 1):

[MAKEINTRESOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a macro that transforms a integer to a string. You use it correctly when you call `CreateDIBFromResource`, but then you apply it again on the result, which makes no sense. You should use the `ImageID` parameter directly. The same applies to the `Instance` parameter.

```
HRESULT DemoApp::CreateDIBFromResource(HWND hWnd, HINSTANCE Instance, LPCWSTR ImageID)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    HBITMAP bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadBitmap(Instance, ImageID);

    return hr;
}
```

BTW, what's the point of returning a `HRESULT`? Shouldn't you return the `HBITMAP`?